# Question filter keeps breaking

Tags: bug, tag-filters

I use a question filter to check for Clojure questions across the entire network.

I checked this morning, and it's intermittently showing "*No questions found*":

[image]

[Link in case it works publically.](https://stackexchange.com/filters/336233/all-clojure?sort=newest)

Sometimes I check and it's working, sometimes it shows nothing.